# Display not appearing

Tags: python, pygame, display

this is one of my first pygame scripts and its a template idea for a loading screen. Just want something basic that opens when run and closes when a key is pressed. I'm not getting any error messages when run and the display does not pop up. How would I get this script to open up that display and wait for that key press?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

# Create the Constants
FPSCLOCK = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # this is my laptops resolution

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BGCOLOR = BLACK

def main(): # includes the entire game process
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT # Use Global Constants Here

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.SysFont('amethystoriginal', 16)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Find your stuff!')

    while True:
        showLoadingScreen()
 
 
def showLoadingScreen():
    loadingFont = pygame.font.SysFont('amethystoriginal', 100)
    loadingSurf1 = loadingFont.render('Find your stuff!', True, WHITE)

    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        loadingRect1 = loadingSurf1.get_rect()
        loadingRect1.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(loadingSurf1, loadingRect1)

        drawPressKeyMsg()

        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get()
            return
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to search.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)

def checkForKeyPress():
    if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
        terminate()

    keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
    if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
        return None
    if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
        terminate()
    return keyUpEvents[0].key

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: sorry about that, above are all the lines that have any sort of connection to display, surface, text, variables, and the used definitions in my program.

Comment: The declaration of `DARKGRAY` and `FPS` as a call to `main()` seems to be missing in this code. Other than that, the application works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was weird this wasn't doing anything for me but that helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `DARKGRAY` and `FPS` as a call to `main()` seems to be missing in this code. Other than that, the application works fine for me.